# ローカルホストでたくさん接続を開始するとエラーになる

Tags: python, linux, network

### 環境

Lubuntu 20.04 64bit
node.js 16.17.1
python 3.8.10

### 再現手順

(1) node.jsを使用し、適当なディレクトリでhttp-serverパッケージのHTTPサーバーをポート8000で起動する

```bash
npx http-server --port 8000
```

(2) pythonスクリプトをclient.pyという名前で用意する

```py
import asyncio

async def client():
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection('127.0.0.1', 8000)
    writer.write(f'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 127.0.0.1\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n'.encode())
    await writer.drain()
    data = await reader.read(10240)
    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()

async def clients(N):
    await asyncio.gather(*[client() for _ in range(N)])

asyncio.run(clients(0x10000))
```

(3) (2)で用意したスクリプトを以下のように実行する

```bash
python3 client.py;ss -an | grep 8000 | grep TIME-WAIT | wc -l
```

※**追記**: ulimit -n 1048576で実行しています

(4) 数分後以下のエラーが(2)の実行端末で表示される

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 14, in <module>
    asyncio.run(clients(0x10000))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "client.py", line 12, in clients
    await asyncio.gather(*[client() for _ in range(N)])
  File "client.py", line 4, in client
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection('127.0.0.1', 8000)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/streams.py", line 52, in open_connection
    transport, _ = await loop.create_connection(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1025, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1010, in create_connection
    sock = await self._connect_sock(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 924, in _connect_sock
    await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 496, in sock_connect
    return await fut
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 501, in _sock_connect
    sock.connect(address)
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
16383
```

### 質問

これは何が起きているエラーなのでしょうか？

### 追記

ちょっと書き換えました。

```py
import asyncio

async def client(id):
    print(f'{id}: started')
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection('127.0.0.1', 8000)
    writer.write(f'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 127.0.0.1\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n'.encode())
    await writer.drain()
    # print(f'{id}: before read')
    data = await reader.read(10240)
    # print(data)
    # print(f'{id}: after read')
    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()
    print(f'{id}: finished')

async def clients(N):
    await asyncio.gather(*[client(i) for i in range(N)])

asyncio.run(clients(0x10000))
```

Comment: `clients`に与える クライアント数が `1`の場合でも正常に動作しますか？(1で動かないようならそもそもムリ)。仮に 1でも動かないようなら, `reader.read` の読み込みバイト数 10とかなら動きますか？ (つまり `http-server`のページのサイズはどのくらい？)

Comment: 簡単に実行できるので書きませんでしたが、0x4000までは普通に実行できますよ。

Comment: 正常に読み取れてますか？ `reader.read` で止まってませんか

Comment: 止まってませんよ。

Comment: `ulimit -n`の結果はいくつになりますか？また、`ulimit -n 65536`と実行した後に実行した場合はどうなりますか？

Comment: 1024ですね。

Comment: 書き換えたソースで、
(...)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 231, in __init__
    _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
0
となります。

Comment: `ulimit -n 65535`を実行した後に同じシェル上で**書き替える前のスクリプト**を実行した場合はどうなりますか？

Comment: あ、すみません。サーバー側が止まってました。今やり直してます。

Comment: まず、**書き換えた後のスクリプト**でそのまま実行した場合、どのclientもfinishedまで到達する前にOSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
16384
になりました。

Comment: fdのmaxは1024です。

Comment: すみません。今見たら1048576でしたね。シェル起動し直したら1024かと思ったのですが...

Comment: 実行をvscode上でやってたので、ファイル変更監視の都合上、この値をいじってたようです。さっき1024で見たのは別の端末で確認していたため、違っていました。

Comment: 1024のままだと、Too many open files 0になっています。

Comment: つまり、最初に答えた1024が間違いで、1048576だったということです。

Comment: スクリプトをVSCodeのターミナル上で実行しているのであれば、質問文にVSCodeのターミナル上で実行していることを追記してください。

Comment: 今普通の端末上でulimit -n 1048576して書き換える前のコードを実行しています。それができたらその旨記述しますね。

Comment: 再現できたので、質問文を修正しました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 調査

コードを以下のように改修し、状況が分かるようにしました。

```py
import asyncio
import logging
import traceback

logger = logging.getLogger('test')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
for ch in [logging.StreamHandler(), logging.FileHandler('client.log')]:
    ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(ch)

async def client(id):
    try:
        logger.debug(f'{id}: started')
        reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection('127.0.0.1', 8000)
        logger.debug(f'{id}: connection established')
        writer.write(f'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 127.0.0.1\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n'.encode())
        await writer.drain()
        # logger.debug(f'{id}: before read')
        data = await reader.read(10240)
        # logger.debug(data)
        # logger.debug(f'{id}: after read')
        writer.close()
        await writer.wait_closed()
        logger.debug(f'{id}: finished')
    except BaseException as err:
        logger.error(f'{id}: ' + traceback.format_exc())

async def clients(N):
    await asyncio.gather(*[client(i) for i in range(N)])

asyncio.run(clients(0x10000))
```

### 結果

```
YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss,sss - test - DEBUG - 0: started
...
YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss,sss - test - DEBUG - 28231: started
YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss,sss - test - DEBUG - 28232: started
YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss,sss - test - ERROR - 28232: Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 501, in _sock_connect
    sock.connect(address)
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
...
(同様の出力が28233～65535まで)
YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss,sss - test - DEBUG - 0: connection established
...
YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss,sss - test - DEBUG - 28231: connection established
YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss,sss - test - DEBUG - 0: finished
...
YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss,sss - test - DEBUG - 28231: finished
```

動的ポートのシステム割当数と正常終了した数を比較すると...

```bash
$ sysctl net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 32768    60999
$ expr 60999 - 32768 + 1
28232
$ grep finished client.log | wc -l
28232
$
```

### 結論

ポートの枯渇が原因で、connect(2)に失敗しているエラーだということが分かりました。
※TIME-WAITの数が16383になっている理由は分かりません。

### 追記

以下に記述したようにTIME-WAITの個数に上限値があるからのようです。
[TIME_WAITなポートが1分経たずに使われる](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/91881/time-wait%e3%81%aa%e3%83%9d%e3%83%bc%e3%83%88%e3%81%8c1%e5%88%86%e7%b5%8c%e3%81%9f%e3%81%9a%e3%81%ab%e4%bd%bf%e3%82%8f%e3%82%8c%e3%82%8b/91883#91883)

Answer (score 4):

`asyncio.open_connection('127.0.0.1', 8000)` は接続相手のポート番号は指定されていますが、自分自身が使用するポート番号は指定されていません。このような場合、TCP/IPでは[ダイナミックポートもしくはエフェメラルポート](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9D%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88_(%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%94%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%83%8D%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%83%AF%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF)#%E3%83%9D%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E7%95%AA%E5%8F%B7%E3%81%AE%E7%A8%AE%E9%A1%9E)と呼ばれるポート番号を使用します。

```
$ sysctl net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 32768    60999
```

手元のマシンでは上記範囲が設定されており、およそ28,000ポートしか用意されていません。

それとは別に、TCP/IPは相手との通信であり、自分が使用を終了したとしても相手が追加データを送ってくる可能性があります。その状態で別のプログラムにポートを割り当ててしまうと後でのプログラムは不正なデータを受信してしまうことになります。そういったトラブルを避けるためのクールダウンタイムとして `TIME_WAIT` 状態で一定時間は再利用できなくなっています。

```
$ sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 60
```

手元のマシンでは60秒は再利用しないことになっていました。

この２つのことがあり、 `asyncio.run(clients(0x10000))` のように65,536回接続しようとしても使用可能なポートが得られず処理を開始できないことがあります。

Comment: ポートが枯渇してるということですね。

Comment: Q&A 自体とは関係ない話題がコメントで続いてしまい、通報も来たので、この会話をチャットに移動しました： https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140072/discussion-on-answer-by-sayuri-